# How to scale a tikz pic that has coordinate inputs?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to scale a tikz pic without scaling its coordinate? In this example, I'm trying first scale my pic and then put it the left of the node. However, the scaling command `\pgftransformscale{0.3}` will rescale the coordinate input also. Maybe I can fixed this by coordinate calculation, but it seems there is a better way. Or should I use other things rather than `tikzset`?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta, positioning}

\tikzset{boxstyle/.style = {draw, ultra thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=2cm}}
\tikzset{
  pics/colorvec/.style n args={3}{
    code = { %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\valt}{#3-0.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\valr}{#3*2}
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=1cm, fill=#2] (chead) at ($#1+(0, 0)$) {};
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=2cm, right=-0.06cm of chead] (elem1) {\small #3};
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=2cm, right=-0.06cm of elem1] (elem2) {\small \valt};
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=2cm, right=-0.06cm of elem2] (elem3) {\small \pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\valr}};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw [thin,dashed][help lines,step=1cm] (0,0) grid (30,10);
\node[draw] (node1) at (3, 3){Node};
%\pic[scale=0.1]{colorvec={(node1.east)}{blue}{0.2}};
\begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{0.3}}\pic{colorvec={(node1.east)}{blue}{0.2}};\end{pgflowlevelscope}

\node[draw] (node2) at (0, 0){Expand the canvas};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to apply certain scale factor to `colorvec` pic and place it with its left most point on certain coordinate. If I'm wrong, please rephrase your question.

The problem with your code is how you place `chead` element. You use its center to place it, therefore it will always cover part of the node used as reference. If you add `anchor=west` in `chead` options, its placement will be at right of first pic parameter.

The scale factor can be applied to pic options.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta, positioning}

\tikzset{boxstyle/.style = {draw, ultra thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=2cm}}
\tikzset{
  pics/colorvec/.style n args={3}{
    code = { %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\valt}{#3-0.5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\valr}{#3*2}
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=1cm, fill=#2, anchor=west] (chead) at ($#1+(0, 0)$) {};
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=2cm, right=-0.06cm of chead] (elem1) {\small #3};
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=2cm, right=-0.06cm of elem1] (elem2) {\small \valt};
        \node [boxstyle, minimum width=2cm, right=-0.06cm of elem2] (elem3) {\small \pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\valr}};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (node1) at (3, 3){Node};
\pic[scale=.3, transform shape]{colorvec={(node1.east)}{blue}{0.2}};
\node[draw] (node2) at (0, 0){Expand the canvas};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I've already told I don't know if this is the intended result. I also don't understand why OP doesn't use a `matrix` or `rectangle multipart` instead of a `pic`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! A few things: 1) the option `scale=0.3, transform shape` is less desired, as it does not scale the thickness of the line. 2) `anchor=west` is not the main reason for the problem. 3) Thanks for telling me `multipart` -- I did not know that.